# Integral functional on algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth complex algebraic variety and $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a real form of $X$.  If $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ is compact and oriented as a real manifold, then it will admit a natural functional
$$
\int_{X}:\mathbb{R}[X_{\mathbb{R}}]\to\mathbb{R}
$$
coming from integration over $X$, where $\mathbb{R}[X_{\mathbb{R}}]$ denotes the polynomial functions on $X_{\mathbb{R}}$.  Complexifying, it follows that we obtain a corresponding functional:
$$
\mathbb{C}\otimes\int_{X}:\mathbb{C}[X]\to\mathbb{C}
$$
However if we started with $X$ over a field which wasn't $\mathbb{C}$, none of the above would make sense.  So my questions are vaguely as follows:

- for an algebraically variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0, is there an analogous notion of $X$ having a 'compact real form'?
- is it possible to algebraically understand where these integration functionals come from?  Without using integration from the analytic setting?

My angle is mostly to understand the situation when $X$ is a homogeneous space for a complex reductive group, so that our integration functional actually defines a coinvariant with respect to the group action.  I want to realize this functional algebraically, without using a Reynolds operator that arises from the semisimplicity of the representation.

Comment: To get the map in the first case, you need a measure on the real form. So it's not just an analogue of having a compact real form, but also some other data. For a reductive group, for integration to define a coinvariant, you need an invariant measure.

Comment: Hi Will, thank you for your comment.  Yes I agree.  For me with the reductive group, $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ will be some compact Riemannian manifold even, and the volume form comes from the Riemannian structure (I'm just working with volume forms and integration of them since I'm assuming orientability)

Comment: One possibility is to take an algebraic $n$-form $\omega$ on $X$ and a class $c$ in the $n$th homology of $X$ (either the singular homology of the complex points or the dual to algebraic de Rham cohomology), then multiply your function by $\omega$ and integrate against $c$. In the reductive case, you can take $\omega$ to be the invariant differential form, and in any case you can take $c$ to be the class of the real points. The class $c$ will exist in greater generality, but I don't know if the proof can be said to avoid the Reynolds operator.